# Semisimple and reductive Lie group and algebra definitions in Wikipedia

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The following two definitions are from Wiki:

> (1)A connected linear algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field is called semisimple if every smooth connected solvable normal subgroup of $G$ is trivial. More generally, a connected linear algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field is called reductive if the largest smooth connected unipotent normal subgroup of $G$ is trivial. This normal subgroup is called the unipotent radical and is denoted $R_{u}(G)$. Source in Wikipedia:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group#Structure_of_semisimple_groups_as_abstract_groups#Definitions

> (2)A connected Lie group is called semisimple if its Lie algebra is a semisimple Lie algebra, i.e. a direct sum of simple Lie algebras. It is called reductive if its Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple and trivial (one-dimensional) Lie algebras. Source in Wikipedia:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Semisimple_and_reductive_groups

From the definition 2, a reductive group is semisimple, but from the definition 1, a semisimple group is reductive.

I hope my logic is correct, but why are there contradictive definitions about these two notions?

Comment: $GL_n(K)$ is a reductive group, but not semisimple. How exactly do you see that "a reductive group is semisimple"? Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ is also reductive and not semisimple.

Comment: From definition 2, it is a direct sum of simple and trivial then it is a direct sum of simple? Is this logic wrong?@dietrichburde

Comment: "trivial" is a bad word choice in the WP article. They mean one-dimensional abelian, which is non-trivial in the sense of non-zero, and the occurrence of these summands makes something reductive but not semisimple.

Comment: Now I believe I have figured out the logic of the wikipedia definition: they actually mean simple Lie algebras and trivial (one-dimensional) Lie algebras BUT NOT each summand is "both simple and trivial"!

Comment: No, they indeed mean it as it appears with, say, $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$. It is the direct product (sum) of a simple Lie algebra, namely $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ and the $1$-dimensional center, which is an abelian Lie algebra with "trivial" Lie brackets, i.e., zero Lie brackets.